# MongoClient Instantiation using IPV6 address throws "MongoException: host and port should be specified in host:port format"

Tags: java, mongodb, ipv6

I am having an issue making a MongoClient using an IPV6 address.

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;

public void testMongoIpV6() {
    final String host = "[2604:fe00:3:1103:250:56ff:fe98:c831]";

    ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress(host, 27017);
    System.out.println(address.getHost());

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(address);
    // Even the code below fails because it delegates the host processing to ServerAddress just like above.
    // MongoClient client2 = new MongoClient(host);
}
```

Exception and stacktrace:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException: host and port should be specified in host:port format

at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.<init>(ServerAddress.java:122)
at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings$Builder.hosts(ClusterSettings.java:102)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:670)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:281)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:277)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:174)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:151)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:121)
```

It seems as though *ServerAddress* is not processing the host correctly. The host initially has []'s around it, but when *ServerAddress* is processing the string, it has stripped it of those []'s and the else block of the *ServerAddress* constructor is called. You can see the code I am referring to here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/ServerAddress.java (Line 113)

I have tried:

- Passing an *Inet6Address* object to *ServerAddress*, same issue (because all it does it call *getHostAddress* on the object and pass the string host to *ServerAddress*.
- Passing the host as a string directly to the *MongoClient* constructor (as seen in the code). This simply passes the host to the *ServerAddress* constructor as the above code has done.

Any assistance or alternative method to allowing the IPV6 address to be used with the MongoClient would be appreciated. Thanks.

Environment details: Mac OS X 10.11.5, Java 7, MongoDB Java Driver V3.2.2.

Comment: There is an open bug: jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2220 try with a: MongoClient client = new MongoClient("[2604:fe00:3:1103:250:56ff:fe98:c831]:27017"); – chf 17 mins ago

Comment: @chf I opened it, so sadly this question might remain unanswered :X

Comment: Using hostnames instead of address literals is always recommended, but you are right: this should work and looks like a bug

Comment: Fixed in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2245